# Centring a div with left, right, and absolute positioning

Tags: css, html, css-position

I have a div with `position:absolute` and I need to get it in the centre of the document. What I thought would work is using `left:50%; top:50%`, but this moves the div 50% from the top and left according to its sides, so it's more to the right and bottom than I'd want. Is there a way to move the div using the centre of it as the focus point?

The height and width both have to be 300px and the div must always be in the centre of the document regardless of the resolution - which is why I can't use static values and have to use percentages

Comment: is `position:absolute` having fixed `height` and `width`??

Comment: 1. What browser support do you need? 2. Are the dimensions of this Div `fixed` or `relative`?

Comment: One trick i've seen is to set the width to 0 and the margins to -(half of the width you want).  That makes the "left" actually point at the center.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

why not try this, its simpler and more general than messing with pixels:

```
.div {
position:absolute;
border:1px solid black;
width:100px;
height:100px;
margin: auto;
top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;

}
```

Comment: I'm about 62% certain this isn't quite valid.  If you have both left  and right...or top and bottom...the position is "overspecified".

Comment: @cHao It is valid, it is a way of making overlays take up the whole screen without having to figure anything out. Problem was, way back, specifying both `left` and `right`, or `top` and `bottom` wouldn't work in IE 6.

Comment: this is the "cleanest" solution, it doesn't depend on the dimensions of the div.

Answer (score 6):

I didn't understood what you meant by *but this moves the document 50% from the top and left* so you should target the `div` and not the container element.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/BbqFU/)

```
div {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background: tomato;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -50px;
    margin-top: -50px;
}
```

Above am using all the properties which you are using, but apart from that am using `margin-left` and `margin-top` with negative values which are equivalent to 1/2 of the elements `height` and `width`

---

Now that's the solution for a fixed `width` element, if your element `width` and `height` are variable, you will have to set your container element to `display: table-cell;` and than use `vertical-align: middle;` to align the element to vertically center, whereas `margin: auto;` will take care of the horizontally center alignment.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/BbqFU/2/)

---

Note: Am using `display: table;` for `body` which is kinda dirty way, so consider using a wrapper element for that and then assign `display: table-cell;` to that, also, make sure you have see all the parent element `height` to `100%`

Comment: @NoobEditor hehe thanks, and Oh I saw you answered as well, but tbh, you don't need calcs...as it is not widely supported yet, also it will increase the properties in your CSS anyways that was something unique so will vote anyways

Comment: `calc` is supported in IE8 too mate...and thats the best you can get!!:) ...check here => http://caniuse.com/#search=calc

Comment: @NoobEditor calc isnt supported on ie8

Answer (score 1):

Based on Mr.Alien's fiddle, i would suggest you to use `calc` for exact middle alignment for fixed dimension width

The idea is to use `calc(50% - 150px);` i.e., **(50% - *half the dimension of the block)***

This way, you can avoid the hacks of :

```
margin-left: -xxpx;
margin-top: -xxpx;
```

**CSS**

```
div {
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    background: tomato;
    position: absolute;
    top: calc(50% - 150px);
    top: -moz-calc(50% - 150px);
    top: -webkit-calc(50% - 150px);
    left: calc(50% - 150px);
    left: -moz-calc(50% - 150px);
    left: -webkit-calc(50% - 150px);
}
```

[**working fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/BbqFU/4/)

Comment: .... assuming you're coding for most modern browsers only. Problem is, for any real-world solution this is not an acceptable solution yet, as calc really isn't that well supported

Answer (score 0):

user2211216 got what I wanted - just use

```
margin: auto;
top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
position: absolute;
```